# How to strip private member function symbols from static lib

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, static-libraries

I'm looking to see if i can strip all the private member function symbols from a static library. my class looks something like the below:

header:

```
#define PUBLIC __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
#define LOCAL  __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))

namspace my_namespace {

class my_class {
public:
  PUBLIC my_class();
  PUBLIC ~my_class();
  PUBLIC void do_something();
private:
  LOCAL float internal_func();
  LOCAL inline float inline_func();
  float member_var_;
}

}
```

cpp:

```
namspace my_namespace {
my_class::my_class(){member_var_ = 0;}
...
void my_class::do_something(){
  ... somecode 
  member_var_ = internal_func();
  member_var_ += inline_func();
}

float my_class::internal_func() {
   ... some code
}

inline float my_class::inline_func(){
  ... some code 
}

}
```

my actual code is much more complex with a number of functions and private member variables with pretty much every function using some member variable so i cant declare them static or remove them from the class.

Ive using the compile flags `-fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden` the inlines flag works fine on functions that have been inlined but im still able to grep `internal_func` out of the `libmy_class.a` file.

Using GNU Strip with `--strip-unneeded` doesn't remove the symbol either i'm still able to grep the private function out.

Am I missing something? or are these symbols just not able to be stripped?

Comment: You'll need to disable support for relocation entirely (not just fpic!) in order to be able to get rid of all the symbols, otherwise the linker is still going to need all of them. And stuff you don't inline / declare as compilation unit scope can't be discarded in any case.

Comment: But generally: Stripping a static library is still somewhat pointless. Even the visibility attribute etc. don't come into effect at all until linked into a shared object.

Comment: If you want a chance at hiding stuff: public interface, pure virtual methods, factory method and the implementation of the interface is placed in an anonymous namespace within the compilation unit, visible only to the factory method and nobody else.